# Display progress when seek bar is moving

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have a `progress bar` in Activity by using code below

```
 private SeekBar seekBar;
 private TextView progressText;

 seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarPercentage);
 progressText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textProgress);
 progressText.setText("Covered:" + "" + seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax());


     seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                    progress = progresValue;
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changing seekbar's progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    progressText.setText("Covered: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

When moving the seek bar, the progress will not changing, it change when the seek bar stopped. How to make the progress changing  while the seek bar is moving ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your only setting progress in the TextView after the tracking stops, so do it while progress is changing:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser){
    progress = progresValue;
    progressText.setText("Covered: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
}
```